# Подключение к удаленному серверу с дин. IP с помощью OpenVPN

Tags: windows, openvpn, rdp, windows-server-2012

Есть удаленный сервер (Windows Server 2012) с динамическим IP. Смогу ли я подключиться к нему по RDP, если на этом сервере поставлю OpenVPN сервер, а на компьютер с которого буду подключаться OpenVPN клиенn?

Comment: Если ip белый и все настройки сети будут верными, то да

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Так подключиться не сможешь, тебе всеравно нужен сервер со статическим IP, [вот в этой инструкции описано](https://blog.vpsville.ru/blog/howto/223.html) как это можно сделать. Ты подымаешь OpenVPN сервер на Linux со статическим IP, подключаешься к нему со своего Windows сервера и аналогично подключаешь клиентов, вы будете в одной локалке где уже и сможешь подцепиться к Windows серверу по RDP на локальный адрес.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Не обязательно. Можно обойтись динамическим DNS